# How can we change the notification centre massage in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios7, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I am sending push notifications from the server to my app successfully. What ever is the notification being send from the server is shown successfully in the notification centre drop down list. But I do not want to show that text in the notification centre that is being given from the centre. For eg. If I send"I Love my country" from the server, then in notification centre drop down view I want to show only the text "Country Lover". But in app the text should receive is "I Love my country".

Hope I able to explain what I want to change in my app.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4

Comment: I founded the solution I just need to Modify my alert type. That's it.

Comment: hello.i have the same problem. could you post your sample here?

Answer (score 0):

Try customising your app using the following method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    for (id key in userInfo) {
       //.. your code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `alert` key (or the `body` of the `alert` for composite `alert`) in the `aps` dictionary of the notification payload will always be displayed in the notification center view.

If by `in app the text should receive` you mean the code that is launched when you tap the notification, you can have an additional custom payload parameter outside the `aps` dictionary that would hold the different text, and you can access it from your code and do whatever you want with it after the user taps the notification to launch the app.

In your example the payload would be :

```
{
  "aps" : { "alert" : "Country Lover" },
  "extra_text" : "I Love my country"
}
```

Of course you should make sure your JSON payload doesn't exceed the max length of 256 bytes.